# Double implication between two sets

Tags: logic

I have two sets A = {s0, s2, s5, s7} and B = {s2, s4, s6, s7} along with a global set S = {s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7}. I want to find a double implication between them: **A↔B** which I know means that A is equivalent to B, or that A and B have the same elements. My result set is **{s2, s7}** but it's wrong. The correct solution mentioned is **{s1, s2, s3, s7}** Can anyone guide the easiest and correct way to find the result set?
Hint: for implication they used the formula: **B U S \A**

Comment: "Double implication between sets" is not a common term (in English at least). Your result $\{s_2,s_7\}$ is the intersection of $A$ and $B$, but it sounds like that's not what you're looking for. Are you looking for a bijection between the two sets?

Comment: I am solving model checking in which I have to calculate implication, OR, AND, and double implication between two sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using your hint:
$$\{x\in S\mid x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in B\}=$$
$$\{x\in S\mid x\in A\rightarrow x\in B\}\cap\{x\in S\mid x\in B\rightarrow x\in A\}=$$
$$\left(B\cup(S\setminus A)\right)\cap\left(A\cup(S\setminus B)\right)=$$
$$\left(B\cup\{s_1,s_3,s_4,s_6\}\right)\cap\left(A\cup\{s_1,s_3,s_5\}\right)=$$
$$\{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_6,s_7\}\cap\{s_0,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_5,s_7\}=$$
$$\{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_7\}.$$

A simpler way (imo) would be (since $P\leftrightarrow Q$ holds iff $P,Q$ are both false or both true):
$$\{x\in S\mid x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in B\}=$$
$$(A\cap B)\cup\left((S\setminus A)\cap(S\setminus B)\right)=$$
$$\{s_2,s_7\}\cup \{s_1,s_3\}.$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Also, if you can tell me the shorter way in comment.